# Unable to use multiple CloudSpatialAnchorWatcher concurrently in current SDK version

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, azure-spatial-anchors

### Current Problem

Using the version 1.3.2 of the Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Unity I get the error

> Cannot run more than one watcher concurrently in this SDK version. Request CV: . Response CV: .

This results in only one watcher running with only a small part of all identifiers I'm looking for.

### What I've done

I'm using the Azure Spatial Anchors SDK for Unity version 1.3.2 and Unity3d 2019.2.5 targeting Android mobile platform.
I initially faced the problem of too many identifiers set to the AnchorLocateCriteria used in the "LocalShared" demo script.

To solve this initial problem I've changed the sample to create multiple instances of CloudSpatialAnchorWatcher instead, each with a smaller portion of the full list of identifiers assigned.
I've set it to a maximum of 20 as this would be below the threshold somewhere around 35 which I've determined by testing it with that number of identifiers as no fixed number is given in the documentation.

After doing some testing with this setup, I assumed it works fine (due to missing try-catch statements) but stumbled across the above mentioned error when digging into the creation of new anchors which at first gave me a different error message.

> An anchor identifier set on AnchorLocateCriteria was invalid. Request CV: . Response CV: .

### Context

I'm at an evaluation state right now and the use case includes the localisation of a user inside of a company building to do fire-rescue and security training. This would require me to be able to create multiple anchors to cover at least an entire floor (which might have 30+ office rooms) and allow the user to locate the anchor closest to him wherever the user is located on the floor.

### Expectations

The documentation does not state any limitations about the number of identifiers used on a single watcher nor does it state anything about only a single watcher can be active at a time thus I at first expected to be able to put as many identifiers into a watcher as wanted or at second to be able to distribute smaller sets of identifiers over multiple watchers.
The error message mentioned above suggests that this might change in a future SDK version and is not an unchangeable limitation.

My primary question is:
How may I locate or detect multiple identifiers (100 or more) or do I have to consider this not possible with Azure Spatial Anchors SDK at the moment.

Additional questions (or things I wonder about) would be if there is any public road-map for Azure Spatial Anchors regarding this issue or if I can expect changes to this sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

We have a limit of 1 watcher and 35 identifiers in current Azure Spatial Anchors SDK.
For others: if this limit is blocking your app to scale up, please reach out to us via [Support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support)